# fixed size unordered_map, how to define?

Tags: c++, unordered-map, fixed-size-types

Is it possible to define a fixed size `unordered_map`?

Looking at the member functions, there is no `resize()` similar to `std::vector` and `std::list`. Also, google didn't help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but there is no such map in the STL. What you can do is write your own class containing an `std::array< std::pair<Key, Value>, N>` and provide most of the `find()`, `insert()` functionality using `std::hash` yourself. If you use a `std::vector< std::pair<Key, Value> >` as data member, you could even have a `resize()` function to only expand the table explicitly, but not implicitly after an `insert()`.

An important thing to realize is that you also need to provide a way to iterate over the various elements, in order to satisfy all the **container requirements**. Typically this is done by having auxiliary data that implements a linked list over all the stored elements.

One issue you need to resolve, however, is which **replacement policy** you use to replace items if your array is full. The `std::unorderd_map` uses so-called chaining, with -for each entry- a dynamically sized **bucket** (with at least forward iteration, so at least equivalent to `forward_list`). Most [chess programs](https://web.archive.org/web/20180713065452/http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Hash+Table) have a fixed-size hash table with a replacement policy to always replace an item if a particular table entry is already occupied.

Answer (score 0):

It is not logically possible for a map to have `resize()` member function, the way other sequence containers has. It is a map, whose every key has to be *unique*. If you resize it to some size, then it has to fill the *newly* created entries with some (default) values. What values should it generate for the keys? How would it ensure the uniqueness of the keys? That decision cannot be made by the map, so it simpley doesn't have `resize()` member function.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to resize map to the known size to avoid further possibly unefficient rehashing, you can use [`std::unordered_map:: reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/reserve). It will set number of buckets, so map could contain given count of elements according to the load factor.

Comment: that only gives more efficiency, but if you keep adding elements, the table will still resize itself dynamically.

Comment: @rhalbersma, yes, but I thought, that TS may be simply wants to optimize table filling when he knows exact count of elements.

Comment: I actually was looking for a fixed size map. So a replacement policy is needed